# Can I define an interface based on a type?

Tags: typescript

How can I define an interface with its keys based on a type? e.g:

```
type FruitTypes = "bananna" | "appple " | "orange";

interface FruitInterface {
  [key: string]: any; // key FruitTypes instead of string
}

// Expected result:
const FruitsObject: FruitInterface = {
  bananna: "Bannana",
  apple: "Apple",
  orange: "Orange",
  mango: "Mango" // Error
};
```

I've tried something like this:

```
interface FruitInterface {
  [key: keyof FruitTypes]: any;
}
```

Maybe there is another way of doing it?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaves like you want it to:

```
const FruitsObject: Record<FruitTypes, any>
```

Is there a specific reason you need an interface ? This is also possible:

```
interface FruitInterface extends Record<FruitTypes, any> {}
const FruitsObject: FruitInterface
```

Comment: Thank you!, that is what I was looking for.